# Biblatex remove dot at the end at footcite and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, macros, bibliographies, citing

like it is said in the heading I need your help at handling dots.
I like to have such a footcite and I do not know how to approach it:
First Name, Last Name, Title, Location, Publisher, Date
And a bibliography like this:
Last Name, First Name, Title, Location, Publisher, Date

This is my present code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrreprt}

% packages
\usepackage[ngerman] {babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top = 2cm, right = 4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

% font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}



%new commands
\newcommand{\quoteInline}[1]{{\small{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\quotepar}[1]{\quote {\quoteInline{#1}}}

% bibliography
\bibliography{Literaturverzeichnis}
\renewcommand\labelnamepunct{\addcomma\space}
```

Thanks for help.

MrXeth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full stop at the end of a `\footcite` and similar footnote citation commands is added by `\bibfootnotewrapper`, the full stop at the end of an entry is controlled by `\finentrypunct`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman] {babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{%
  \bibsentence#1}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote reads "Emma Sigfridsson und Ulf Ryde, »Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments«. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P" without a period at the end. Similarly for the bibliography entry]

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to let the bibliography look like an enumeration?

Comment: @MrXeth That would be a new question, I think. What exactly do you have in mind? `verbose-ibid` does not work with numbers (the footnote numbers are just incidental and are subject to change: numbers can be skipped if you cite a source multiple times or use normal footnotes in between). So how would the bibliography be numbered?

Comment: like: - entry1 -entry2 -entry3

Comment: And there is also another problem: between the title and the publisher is still a dot. do you maybe know, how to fix it?

Comment: @MrXeth The question about the dot is also a new question (which I see you have asked already). It is usually better to focus one question on one particular issue and not to change the requirements after an answer has been given.