# Dots in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I like to have footcite likt this:
First Name, Last Name, Title, Location, Publisher, Date and a bibliography like this: Last Name, First Name, Title, Location, Publisher, Date

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman] {babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{%
  \bibsentence#1}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
```

The problem is the dot between the title and the location. I also like to have a enumerated bibliography like
-source1
-source2
...

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please complete your given code snippet to br compilable! Do not forget to add two bib entries to your question ...

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. The two issues (i) dot between title and location and (ii) enumerated bibliography are sufficiently remote that they can be answered in different questions without interference. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. I also still don't quite understand the desired output for the enumerated bibliography. Do you just want an `itemize`-d bibliography with just dashes or bullet points instead of a numbered bibliography?

Comment: I like to have bullet points.

Comment: That is  very unusual, but should be doable. Please ask a *new* question about that so that this question here can be focussed on one thing only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to turn all generic punctuation in the bibliography and citation into a comma instead of a full stop/period. That can be achieved easily by redefining `\newunitpunct`. If you redefine `\newunitpunct` you don't even need to modify `nametitledelim`.

Recycling the MWE from [Biblatex remove dot at the end at footcite and bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466619/35864)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman] {babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{%
  \bibsentence#1}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum\autocite{nussbaum} dolor\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote 2: "Martha Nussbaum, Aristotle’s »De Motu Animalium«, Princeton: Princeton University Press, 1978" the bibliography entry is similar. The entry for <code>sigfridsson</code> also features commas now.]

Comment: Thank you again! But what does actually * mean at the end of \renewcommand ?

Comment: @MrXeth Usually the star in `\(re)newcommand` marks a macro that is not `\long` as opposed to the unstarred version that defines a `\long` macro: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/35864. In this case the difference is not significant for most intents and purposes and I chose the starred version out of habit.